# Is there an easy way to calculate a formula in Python conditional on the Len of input

Tags: python, for-loop, formula, modulo

I'm completely at a loss on how to do this, so any suggestions/hints would be appreciated.

```
((6778 // (6*7*8*9)) * 1000) + 
(((6778 % (6*7*8*9)) // (7*8*9)) * 100) +
(((6778 % (6*7*8*9) % (7*8*9)) // (8*9)) *10)+
(6778 % (6*7*8*9) % (7*8*9) % (8*9) // 9)
```

Output = 21311

has to work for multiple integers, not just 6778

I've tried a for loop, but its proving difficult

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: practising and getting used to coding

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand at all. What does the number 6778 have to do with the expression? What is the actual *formula*? That is, what is the rule that explains, step by step, what you should do with the input? When you say you "tried a for loop", what exactly was the code that you wrote? When you say that you want to calculate this "conditional on the len of input", what exactly does that mean? What should change when the input length changes? Also, you do understand that integers don't have a length, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to use a recursive function that calls itself until a certain condition is met. I have to say that your example is not really clear so I only tried to solve the recurrent part of the numerator of all of your blocks. I am going to post the code here for reference for you but I am not sure it does what you would like to acheive, if you could give us more guidelines we will be able to help you even further

```
        x = 6778
    def split_val(x):
        return [float(i) for i in str(x)]

    def perc_calculation(x, i, val):
        if i > 0:
            list_num = split_val(x)
            prod_val = np.prod([list_num[0] + num for num in range(len(list_num))][(i-1):])
            val = val % prod_val
            return perc_calculation(x, i-1, val)
        else:
            return val
    out_val = 0
    for i in range(len(str(x))):
        list_num = split_val(x)
        prod_val = np.prod([list_num[0] + num for num in range(len(list_num))][(i):])
        numerator = perc_calculation(x,i,x)
        print(numerator)
```

This is the result:
6778
730.0
226.0
10.0

As you may notice the perc_calculation function is a recursive function because it calls itself